# Show Place name shown in Camera View

Tags: android, augmented-reality, location-based-service

I am making an AR based android app.

I have my current location coordinates + nearby places coordinates and names + Bearing between current location and nearby places + azimuth.

I am stuck at how to show all the nearby places' names that are visible in camera and comes under radar region? what should be the next steps?

Ps. I don't mind using any 3rd party tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Place Search Web API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) to get a list of businesses/points of interest around your GPS location. This data contains latitude, longitude, name and a lot more.

You should run a service or async task in the background to fetch data on places around the user when the app is launched. If the user is moving, then you can either use Location Manager to get updated coordinates when the user moves a certain distance and then call the web service again or keep polling for the users GPS locations and when you notice a significant change, get a new set of places.

Then you just have to plot this information in your camera's field of view. For this you can look at the [Augmented Reality Tutorial](https://github.com/alphamu/augmented-reality-tutorial) I created. Look at the "**Having something to draw**" section onwards.

The Place Search API is free for certain amounts of usage. As per Google's terms and conditions, you can't store any of this data on the device or your own personal database.

Comment: Thanks for telling place api's terms & conditions.